# What's with the time travelling delay in The Time Machine by H.G.Wells?

Tags: time-travel, the-time-machine

I recently got *The Time Machine* by H.G.Wells and I am quite intrigued by this line near the end of the story :-

> "But is it not some hoax?" I said. "Do you really travel through time?"
>
> "Really and truly I do." And he looked frankly into my eyes.
> He hesitated. His eye wandered about the room. "I only want **half an
> hour,**" he said. "I know why you came, and it's awfully good of you.
> There's some magazines here. If you'll stop to lunch I'll prove you this
> time travelling up to the hilt, specimens and all. If you'll forgive
> my leaving you now?"

In the paragraph above, I have highlighted the words - "half an hour" - as I am slightly confused by the fact that even though he had the power to travel to any point in time he wanted, he asked for half an hour of time. He could have just time travelled, obtained his specimens, and returned with them moments later, although in reality, he would have travelled to the future and back again.

Why does he ask for such a long time here? Was he trying to prevent a paradox? He did not need to get ready or anything, because the author briefly left and then returned almost immediately to tell the Time Traveller that he had an appointment, and the Time Traveller had already departed.

Why did he ask for so much time?

Comment: Half an hour is such a long time? Maybe he just wanted a chance to wash up and change into clean clothes after his travel?

Comment: @user14111 - Who knows?

Comment: He was going to use the time machine to bring back some proof, then get the (presumably very messy) room tidied up.

Comment: @Valorum - quite possible. But that does not seem very likely as an explanation. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, we know that traveling leaves the room dishevelled.

Comment: Another possibility is that he doesn't want to return to the same point in spacetime, and a half-hour delay may be sufficient to ensure that he doesn't, within the margin of error inherent in his machine.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron - very likely theory. But one line (by the Time Traveller himself) says that he saw someone travel like a rocket across the room (don't ask me who, I haven't even memorized the book yet!) and I would really like o estimate that it takes about 15 seconds to travel an entire room and that would be like 0.5 seconds to the Traveller. Assuming it takes him 2 seconds to realize that the time he is returning to is not the same as he started, 30 seconds seems to be a reasonable amount of time. Anyway, he built the machine and was quite good at handling it by the looks.

Comment: @InfinityMilestone Perhaps he was recalling that on his way back, as he slowed down the rewinding, that was the first point time, going backwards, that he was sure of seeing the lab well and not as a confusing blur, and he recalled that from his perch on the active machine during that moment, he had not seen his idle machine in the lab at that time, so he knew that for whatever reason, he would not be returning quite then. Had he gotten a good view for a bunch of days of the future, he'd have already known the machine would never return to the lab.

Comment: The book leaves quite a few questions like this, many of which you'll find answers too in the unofficial sequel, The Time Ships by Stephen Baxter.  It's a good book, in my opinion.